# KubeCTL with Postgres query doesn't work and throws "LINE 1: select * FROM "employees" where employeeData::text like someSampleHere;"

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubectl, postgresql-9.1

The field `employeeData` is of type `json`.

Consider the query:

```
select * FROM "employees" where employeeData::text like '%someSampleHere%'
```

When I'm running the query inside Postgres it works perfect and I get the rows that I'm asking for.

However when I use it with KubeCTL and running this query outside of the PG App

```
psql -d employess_db -U postgres -c 'select * FROM "employees" where employeeData::text like 'someSampleHere';'
```

PG throws

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: select * FROM "employees" where employeeData::text like %someSampleHere%;
```

How can we fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a quoting problem to me. You neglected to show your actual `kubectl` command line in your question, but this works for me without any errors:

```
kubectl exec postgres-pod -- psql -U postgres -d employees_db \
  -c "select * from \"employees\" where employeeData::text like '%someSampleHere%'"
```

Comment: The double quotes around `employees` aren't needed to begin with

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: I'd usually prefer to switch to dollar quoting in psql:  `-c 'select * FROM employees where employeeData::text like $$%someSampleHere%$$;'`